# Hibernate enum inserting starts from 0 should start from 1

Tags: java, hibernate

Well when i use the enum type and insert into database all type values starts from 0 not 1. Any easy fixes the +1 is not good solution.

The Enum class

```
public enum ServiceRequestType {
    REGISTERED(1), REJECTED(2), DONE(3);

    int value;
    ServiceRequestType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Also the hibernate mapping.

```
    <property name="type" column="service_request_status_type_fk">
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">ee.ttu.support.model.domain.service.ServiceRequestType</param>
        </type>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java5 enum types. Check [this](http://tkdao.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/mapping-java-5-enums-with-hibernate/) link for perfect enum example with hibernate. Let me know if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
public enum ServiceRequestType
{
    REGISTERED = 1, REJECTED, DONE
}
```

If you want to get the enum from int, you can do `Enum.ToObject(typeof(ServiceRequestType), 1)`

Comment: Are you sure you can use the = in ENUMs ?

Comment: The question seems to be about java, where this is invalid syntax, not c#.

Comment: You are completely right, this is C# syntax. This was before I had my coffee... ¬_¬

Answer (score -1):

Well i did not find any easy solutions for this simple problem but here is one

```
public enum ServiceRequestType {
    REGISTERED, REJECTED, DONE;

    public int getIndex() {
        return ordinal() + 1;
    }
}
```

And when calling out use the .getIndex method

```
ServiceRequestType.REGISTERED.getIndex()
```